# How to delete history in a range in linux bash

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, command-history

Fooling around with Linux on my Pi and ran into this problem. I found that you can remove a certain line with the command `history -d  linenumber` but what if I want to remove a range (which I think is much more practical)? So I looked up how to loop in several places. Both ways of looping worked for an echo but not for the history command. I think it's because "history" is not actually a command. But why does this matter? Is there a simple way of doing this? I never knew looping was possible in Linux bash so now I'm pretty curious! Here's what I did:

`pi@raspberry:~$ for ((i=258;i<=262;++i)); do "history -d $i"; done;` // which is incorrect due to quotes, giving:

`-bash: history -d 258: command not found
-bash: history -d 259: command not found
-bash: history -d 260: command not found
-bash: history -d 261: command not found
-bash: history -d 262: command not found`

This below should work (but it doesn't):

`pi@raspberry:~$ for i in {5..10}; do history -d $i; done;`

`-bash: history: 5: history position out of range`

I found an article here: https://superuser.com/questions/649859/history-position-out-of-range-when-calling-history-from-bash-script

... but they were not clear at all and said something along the lines that it needs to be sourced instead of executed, which actually means nothing to me. If it can't be done through the command line just say so. Otherwise, I am going to be brushing up on Python, and if that's a logical way of doing it, it'd be nice to know.

Thanks

Comment: The second command fails because there is no entry at offset 5. Check `history` where it starts and ends.

Comment: Hint: If you delete position 10 in a list, the entry in position 11 moves to position 10 if the entry in position 11 existed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
for ((i=258;i<=262;++i)); do "history -d $i"; done;
```

as you said, is simply not working due to quotes

```
for i in {5..10}; do history -d $i; done;
```

is working, but you must ensure to have entries from 5 to 10, which in your examples, you don't have.
Take into account that every item you remove, the position indexes of the other items scale down of one.

Basically you should **reverse** loop items:

```
for i in {10..5}; do history -d $i; done;
```

to not be affected by the position index changes while looping.

**Edit**
As Cyrus suggested, there's another approach.
You want to remove items from 258 to 262, a total of 5 entries (262 is included)
You can delete 5 times the entry at position 258.
Taking advantage of the index scaling down of one every time you delete an item:

- the first time, you delete the item 258
- the second time, you delete the ex-item 259, that has scaled down to 258
- the third time, you delete the ex-ex-item 260, that has scaled down to 259 (in the first delete) and to 258 (in the second delete)
- the fourth time, you delete the ex-ex-ex-item 261, that has scaled down to 260 (in the first delete), to 259 (in the second delete) and to 258 (in the third delete)
- the fifth time, you delete the ex-ex-ex-ex-item 262...

Comment: Yep, as Cyrus hinted in his comment. So the way I was doing it I would delete every other command since the stack becomes shorter and the variable increments at the same time, each loop. Cool!

I guess now I see why some would suggest just do the loop for however many histories to delete, without any variable.

Comment: I edited the message trying to explain the other method to delete items

Comment: Great answer, but could you post some code illustrating the second example? I keep running into a `history position out of range` error.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the entries exist.

If you want to delete the entries 258 to 262, then delete the entry 258 five times.